# Java db schema does not exist (netbeans 7)

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I created a java db database using netbeans 7 services, I used the java embedded driver to connect to the java db.
I can find my database under the connection in the java database, under a schema called ROOT.

This is my java db connection name:

```
jdbc:derby:AddressBook [root on ROOT]
```

But, when i try to use that schema in my project i get an exception that states

```
Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'ROOT' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
                       .....
```

The error apears in the select statement. what should i do to make it readable in the project?

This is my code:

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:derby:AddressBook";
   private static final String USERNAME = "root";
   private static final String PASSWORD = "cs101";

   private Connection connection = null; // manages connection
   private PreparedStatement selectAllPeople = null; 
   private PreparedStatement selectPeopleByLastName = null; 
   private PreparedStatement insertNewPerson = null; 

   // constructor
   public PersonQueries()
   {
      try 
      {
         connection = 
            DriverManager.getConnection( URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD );

         // create query that selects all entries in the AddressBook
         selectAllPeople = 
            connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM ROOT.Addresses" )
```

Comment: Try `Addresses` instead of `ROOT.Addresses`.

Comment: Addresses was my initial, but then i changed it to ROOT.Addresses hoping it might read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this code before creating the connection

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver")
```

Comment: More likely the embedded driver, not the client driver, since the URL syntax in the original post is embedded syntax rather than client syntax.

Answer (score 0):

when using embedded derby nb has placed your db in a specific location. in my NB 7.2 install it defaults to: C:\Users\James.netbeans-derby. you need to make sure your app is reading the same db file by setting the derby home property:

```
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "C:\Users\James\.netbeans-derby");
```

or like this:

```
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", 
    System.getProperty("user.home")+".netbeans-derby");
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Get the Complete URL from the properties of Derby Database and get the connection to resolve the issue